# Android store custom files

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to install custom files along with my Android Application. These files will be further read by my programs.

Where and how should I save/export them in the android file system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in the assets/ folder. You can read files there with the [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have no assets folder in my Android directory structure

Comment: You can create that directory yourself and the build system will see it and use it. Read up on the structure of Android projects [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)